# Why some file in R packages has '.q' extensions and what is `0aaa.r` file for?

Tags: r, file

I was looking after some solution in the [cluster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cluster/index.html) R package source  ([ddl tar](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/cluster_1.15.2.tar.gz)), when I noticed that in the folder named `R` some files has .q extensions.

Does anybody knows why some functions were created in `.r` extensions and the others in `.q` extensions? When someone creates an overloaded functions, they got to be in file with `.q` extension?

Thanks for any help and information about that.

EDIT

Also I noticed that in the folder named `R` there is a file named `0aaa.r`

Does anybody knows what this file is for? When some1 writes a package, is that file is a must?

Thanks for any help and information about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing some documentation.

> Extensions .S and .s arise from code originally written for S(-PLUS),
>   but are commonly used for assembler code. Extension .q was used for S,
>   which at one time was tentatively called QPE. (R is a dialect of S).

Source: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html

Comment: Whoah, what a long instruction :)